# Wget how to save file in particular location

Tags: linux, wget

I am using this command

**wget -r --accept "*.ext" --level 2 "example.com/index1/"**

which is working fine. now i want to define path and file name where i want to save my file

Any suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-O` option of `wget`.  For example:

```bash
wget -O report.pdf http://www.example.com/files/awkward-name.pdf
```

Note however, that it is only really useful if you are downloading a *single* document.

From the manual page:

> Use of `-O` is *not* intended to mean simply “use the name file instead of the one in the URL;” rather, it is analogous to shell redirection: `wget -O file http://foo` is intended to work like `wget -O - http://foo > file`; file will be truncated immediately, and all downloaded content will be written there.

Since you appear to be using the `-r` option, you might be better off downloading all files into a temporary current working directory and only after that is done decide what to do with them.

```bash
mkdir /tmp/download/
cd /tmp/download/
wget http://www.example.com/files/awkward-name.pdf
cd -
cp /tmp/download/awkward-name.pdf report.pdf
rm -rf /tmp/download/
```

Comment: Could  you please provide me example. i want to download only pdf files

Comment: i used this command 

wget - r-- accept  *.pdf -O ../pdfs/" + fileName + ".pdf -- level 2 " + 'https://github.com/broofa/node-mime/archive/master.zip' stil it is creating file

Comment: What you are showing clearly isn't something you'd expect to work in a shell.

Answer (score 1):

You could use -O option with [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Logging-and-Input-File-Options) like below:

```
wget google.com -O \usr\user\myfolder\foo.html
```

Comment: i want to downlaod only pdf files